# The Magicians Series - a passage about how hard and frustrating studying magic is

Tags: quotes, the-magicians

There is a passage in The Magicians Series about how hard and frustrating is studying magic. It describes the hard work Quentin puts in the learning magic and staying a lot in the library.

I searched for days but I couldn't find. Could you please help me.

Comment: *It was frustrating having to pound levels while the others were off doing God knew what. She was running through new fields of power, frisking through them, but she was already eager to get on to whatever it was the rest of them were up to. She kept trying to run ahead, and Iris had to drag her back and make her trudge through the levels in order. I mean, it was so blindingly obvious that if you took the kinetic elements from level 112, and borrowed the reflexive bits from the self-warming spell at level 44, then you had a basic working model for how to make yourself hover...*

Comment: Or: *That was before. Now there was no time when Quentin wasn’t studying. As often as Eliot had warned him about what he was in for, and as hard as he’d worked up till now, he still somehow imagined that learning magic would turn out to be a delightful journey through a secret garden where he would gaily pluck the heavy fruit of knowledge from conveniently low-hanging branches. Instead every afternoon after P.A. Quentin went straight to the library to rush through his regular homework so he could betake himself after dinner to the library, where his appointed tutor waited for him.*

Comment: @Valorum , you are answering in the comments because…?

Comment: @Lexible - Because there's a bunch of potentially relevant comments. I was hoping OP would pick one that I could turn into a proper answer.

Comment: Were either of these the passages you had in mind?

Comment: @valorum unfortunately not the exact one I’m looking for buy they are close.